# Qt6: How to customize a QTableView highlight?

Tags: python-3.9, pyside6, qt6

I want to customize how the highlight looks when an item is selected in the table, specifically change the area that is highlighted when an item is selected. However, for some reason this code, which has previously worked in another project of mine, is now not working as expected.

Previously working MRE:

```py
from PySide6 import QtCore as qtc
from PySide6 import QtGui as qtg
from PySide6 import QtWidgets as qtw

class ListItemsDelegate(qtw.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter: qtg.QPainter, option: qtw.QStyleOptionViewItem, index: qtc.QModelIndex) -> None:
        if option.state & qtw.QStyle.StateFlag.State_Selected:
            painter.fillRect(
                    qtc.QRect(
                        option.rect.left(),
                        option.rect.top(),
                        20,
                        option.rect.height()
                    ),
                    qtc.Qt.GlobalColor.blue,
            )
        option.state &= ~qtw.QStyle.StateFlag.State_Selected
        option.state &= ~qtw.QStyle.StateFlag.State_HasFocus
        painter.drawText(option.rect.topLeft(), "text")

app = qtw.QApplication()

model = qtc.QStringListModel([1, 2, 3])
view = qtw.QListView()
view.setModel(model)
view.setItemDelegate(ListItemsDelegate())
view.show()

app.exec()
```

Previously working image:

[image]

Now not working MRE:

```py
from PySide6 import QtCore as qtc
from PySide6 import QtGui as qtg
from PySide6 import QtWidgets as qtw

class TableItemsDelegate(qtw.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter: qtg.QPainter, option: qtw.QStyleOptionViewItem, index: qtc.QModelIndex) -> None:
        if option.state & qtw.QStyle.StateFlag.State_Selected:
            highlight_rect = qtc.QRect(option.rect)
            highlight_rect.adjust(20, 20, -20, -20)
            painter.fillRect(
                    highlight_rect,
                    qtc.Qt.GlobalColor.blue,
            )
        option.state &= ~qtw.QStyle.StateFlag.State_Selected
        option.state &= ~qtw.QStyle.StateFlag.State_HasFocus
        painter.drawText(option.rect.topLeft(), "text")

class TableModel(qtc.QAbstractTableModel):
    def data(self, *args) -> int:
        return 1

    def rowCount(self, *args) -> int:
        return 5

    def columnCount(self, *args) -> int:
        return 5

app = qtw.QApplication()

view = qtw.QTableView()
view.setModel(TableModel())
view.setItemDelegate(TableItemsDelegate())
view.show()

app.exec()
```

Not working image:

[image]

They're both quite literally the same code yet I only get the custom highlight with the `QListView`, while I get both the custom highlight and the default highlight with `QTableView`, why would that be?

Comment: Both your codes have many issues: 1. `data()` should not arbitrarily return an integer; 2. the given style option should not be modified, and you should instead create a copy of it whenever you need to change it in the function scope (but you're not even using it, so what's the point?); 3. adjusting a rectangle is not the same as explicitly providing its coordinates (so, no, they're *not* "quite the same"); 4. complex text drawing requires the original bounding rect, so it should *at least* be `painter.drawText(option.rect, 0, "text")` (with 0 referring to the text alignment/option flags).

Comment: That said, the issue is probably caused by the style: if the current style uses the QCommonStyle as default, it will always draw the selection rectangle using the highlight palette role. If you don't want that, either use a QProxyStyle that overrides `drawPrimitive()` and behaves like the default (but ignoring the selected state), or clear the paint rect either by filling the rectangle *again* with the `Base` palette role, or using an appropriate composition mode for the painter before drawing anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a custom style and applied that to the `QTableView` object:

```py
class GridViewStyle(qtw.QProxyStyle):
    # To hide default selection highlight.
    def drawPrimitive(self, element, option, painter, widget=None) -> None:
        # Check if selected:
        if option.state & qtw.QStyle.StateFlag.State_Selected:
            # if selected, remove the State_Selected StateFlag,
            option.state &= ~qtw.QStyle.StateFlag.State_Selected
            # drawPrimitive call now does everything it does, except draw selection highlight,
            super().drawPrimitive(element, option, painter)
            # re-add State_Selected StateFlag so paint() in delegate can use it.
            option.state |= qtw.QStyle.StateFlag.State_Selected
        else:
            super().drawPrimitive(element, option, painter)
```